# SQL or NOSQL Database to store web analytics on heroku

Tags: database, heroku, nosql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, analytics

I'm developing a heroku rails app. I want to record analytics for the app. I was going to just throw them in the Postgres DB, but thought this may be a bad idea - since that data's going to grow a lot faster than any other data, and perhaps will hurt the performance or scalability of the other data?

I'm thinking to push it instead into a MongoDB.

I'm not really experienced with the NoSQL options out there, have googled for a straight answer but most of the answers I've found are in more general terms, like what kind of database qualities are needed for this kind of application without getting into specifics about which DB's offer those qualities.

The analytics will eventually be used by the app to customise output - eg higher rankings for frequently clicked objects - so I'm looking for my own storage rather than an analytics service, unless you can convince me that my app can efficiently and flexibly query that service.

Comment: In the end, I went with Mongo because (a) I was already using it for another part, and (b) it has simple integration into Heroku through mongolabs

Answer (score 2):

I do Ruby and Couchbase! Couchbase is often used for these sorts of purposes due to the ability handle extreme write volume and being so easy to scale. You get RAM speed performance. It is an evolution of memcached (became Membase Server became Couchbase Server). With the Map/Reduce Indexes and Elastic Search Integration you can do a lot with indexing and querying as well.

Getting used to Documents and JSON for your model takes a little getting used to coming from SQL but, once you get the hang of it, get comfortable, it's hard to go back.

I have a couple microsites: http://CouchbaseOnRails.com and http://CouchbaseModels.com to help with getting started. They are a work in progress, but hopefully you find it helpful. Also you can find good info on: http://www.couchbase.com/develop/ruby/current

I can certainly help you get started, find me @scalabl3

Comment: Thanks for the tip scalabl3.
As mentioned though, I'm using heroku - it appears they don't have a couch Addon.
I'm a small team at the moment so looking to keep server admin to a minimum.
Do you know of a good couch hosting service (something like [MongoHQ](http://www.mongohq.com)) that I could use to keep server admin down?